# Running a loop/multiple lines in vs code python debug console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

How do I run a simple loop in VS Code's python debug console? When I try to enter the following:

```
for el in dataset:
```

It gives me the error below. I seem to be able to enter variable names, but not multi-line commands like I can in the normal python REPL.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 416, in evaluate_expression
    compiled = compile(_expression_to_evaluate(expression), '<string>', 'eval')
  File "<string>", line 1
    for el in dataset:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 969, in internal_evaluate_expression_json
    pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(py_db, frame, expression, is_exec=True)
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 368, in new_func
    return _run_with_unblock_threads(original_func, py_db, curr_thread, frame, expression, is_exec)
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 336, in _run_with_unblock_threads
    return _run_with_interrupt_thread(original_func, py_db, curr_thread, frame, expression, is_exec)
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 307, in _run_with_interrupt_thread
    return original_func(py_db, frame, expression, is_exec)
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 418, in evaluate_expression
    Exec(_expression_to_evaluate(expression), updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 1
    for el in dataset:
                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Typically what I'd do is evaluate a list comprehension if that expression is simple. For more complex expressions, I'm not sure what VSC offers but PyCharm offers a specific way to evaluate more complex expressions during debugging (e.g., with loops).

Comment: The traceback you gave doesn't match the example code. In the traceback, `for el in dataset` doesn't have a colon `:` at the end.

Comment: @MattDMo, thanks, yeah I just noticed that myself. Should be fixed.

Comment: @cicolus, list comprehensions do seem to work a little better. thanks.

Comment: just curious...can you just run the REPL in one of the VS code windows (I'm not a VS Code user) to solve this problem?

Comment: @Steve well, not to get live access to the variables during debugging.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Write the command in a new editor window, then simply copy and paste the code in the debug console and press `Enter`
2. Write the command directly in the debug console. When you want to enter a new line, press `Shift+Enter`. When the command is complete, execute with `Enter`

Comment: Ah, the good ol' `Shift+Enter`. Now I feel silly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

2.1. Write the command directly in the debug console. Type {} at the end of current line, then press shift+enter. After complete writing all lines, press enter to execute.

> ```
> for i in [1,2,3]: {'''press shift+enter here'''}
> for i in [1,2,3]: {
>     print(i)  #press enter here
> }
> ```

Reference
https://youtu.be/p8zMXKFlkqk?t=50

Comment: I think this is covered by Option 2 of GZZ's answer.